# Country & State picklist as custom fields

Tags: custom-field, country-and-state

Is the State and Country picklists available as custom fields?
Can I define a custom field of type Country and use the 'built in' Country values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Winter 14 you have this feature on Salesforce.

For standard fields **type address** now you can have a predefined and managed list of countries and states.

You only have to activate it.

> From Setup, click Data Management | State and Country Picklists.
>   On the State and Country Picklists setup page, click Enable to turn on the picklists.

Take care about this change because the values that you will be able to set on those fields should be part of the list.

More info: 
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_state_country_picklists_overview.htm&language=en_US

### Custom field

However, if you need this list as a custom field, you'll have to create a picklist custom field. Some consideration about this:

1. If you need translations, you'll should set the values as code (typically ISOCode) and then translate those codes for each language.
2. If you create States as dependent picklist be careful about the amount of values (the limit is 1500), In my experience it is better to use a text field.

Answer (score 3):

salesforce doesn't have data type as country.Instead create a two custom fields
country--------picklist(data type).
state----------multi picklist(data type).

Use field dependency :state based on country selection